# Need AndroidArchitecture Paging Library to continue fetching pages after sending it an empty list

Tags: android-architecture-components, android-paging

I'm using AndroidArchitecture Paging Library 1.0.0 successfully with a PageKeyedDataSource. But, my service will sometimes return an empty list even though subsequent pages will have items. In loadInitial method, I call:

callback.onResult(emptyList, nextPageToLoad)

Because, I pass it an empty list, it thinks there are no more pages to load and won't call loadAfter. However, I need it to continue to load more pages. I could detect the empty list condition and pass it a non-empty list with fake items. However, then I need to hack my adapter to filter out those fake items. Is there an easier way to get the paging lib to continue fetching pages after sending it an empty list? FYI: my nextPageToLoad is 2 in this case. Also, I've tried Paging Lib 1.0.1 and it didn't make a difference.